# get the protein that contains specific sequence using OLEDB

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

Here is a background on my program: each protein is made from a sequence of amino acids(or AA)

I have some tables :tblProInfo(that contains general info about proteins),tblOrderAA(that contains the sequence(AA sequence) of specific protein(for each protein there is a serial number that i set before))

now, I'm trying to retvive the science names of the protein that contains part of sequence that the user put in textbox1. It is likely that more than one protein contains the sequence that the user typed.

Here is my code. I got "Syntax error" and I'm sure I have more mistakes.Please HELP me!

```
        public void OpenDB()
    {
        dataConnection = new OleDbConnection();
        try
        {
            dataConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Projects_2012\\Project_Noam\\Access\\myProject.accdb";
            dataConnection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error accessing the database: " +
                             e.Message,
                             "Errors",
                             MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                             MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

private string FromCodonsToProtein(string codons)
    {
        OpenDB();
        int sizePro=0, i,counter=0,serialPro;
        string st="",tempst="";

        OleDbCommand datacommand = new OleDbCommand();
        datacommand.Connection = dataConnection;
        datacommand.CommandText = "SELECT tblProInfo.proInfoAAnum, tblProInfo.proInfoSerialNum,tblProInfo.proInfoScienceName FROM tblProInfo";
        OleDbDataReader dataReader = datacommand.ExecuteReader();
        while(dataReader.Read())
        {
            sizePro = dataReader.GetInt32(counter);
            serialPro= dataReader.GetInt32(counter+1);
            counter++;
              OleDbCommand cmd= new OleDbCommand();
              cmd.Connection = dataConnection;
              cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblOrderAA.orderAACodon1 FROM tblOrderAA"
                               +"WHERE (((tblOrderAA.orderAASerialPro)='"+serialPro+"'))";

              OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            tempst="";
            for (i = 0; i > sizePro; i++)
            {
                tempst = tempst + rdr.GetString(i);
            }
            if (tempst.Contains(codons))
            {
                st = st + " \n" + dataReader.GetString(counter);
            }
        }
            return st;


    }
```

Comment: Where do you have syntax error?

Comment: i fix the syntax error. now i have this error(sorry if it isn't understandable, i transleted it to ENGLISH) `Non-matching criteria to expression data type.` in this line: `OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a space here

```
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblOrderAA.orderAACodon1 FROM tblOrderAA" 
                       +"WHERE (((tblOrderAA.orderAASerialPro)='"+serialPro+"'))";
```

rewrite in this way

```
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblOrderAA.orderAACodon1 FROM tblOrderAA"  
                       +" WHERE (((tblOrderAA.orderAASerialPro)='"+serialPro+"'))"; 
                      // ^ here
```

However you should use parametrized query (also with msaccess) to avoid possible errors and injection attacks.
Another problem is the global dataConnection. Don't do that, you gain nothing in this way.
Return the connection and encapsulate it with a using statement.

For example:

```
public OleDbConnection OpenDB()   
{   
    dataConnection = new OleDbConnection();   
    dataConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Projects_2012\\Project_Noam\\Access\\myProject.accdb";   
    dataConnection.Open();   
    return dataConnection;
}
```

then in the calling code use this syntax

```
using(OleDbConnection cnn = OpenDB())
{
    // in the rest of your code, replace dataConnection with cnn
    // The using statement will ensure that in the case of exceptions
    // your connection will be allways closed and properly disposed

    ........

}
```

EDIT: Can't give you a full working solutions, too many aspects of your problem are unknown to me, however a great simplification will be to change your query in this way

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       tblProInfo.proInfoAAnum, 
       tblProInfo.proInfoSerialNum,
       tblProInfo.proInfoScienceName 
FROM   tblProInfo LEFT JOIN tblOrderAA 
  ON   tblOrderAA.orderAASerialPro = tblProInfo.proInfoSerialNum

WHERE  tblOrderAA.orderAACodon1 = @codons
```

Try it directly in access using its query editor, if it works as you expected then change your code. You don't need two query and crossed loops to get the results.

Comment: i'm getting unhandled error in this line : `OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Comment: Yes, that's because in the sql string is missing the space before the WHERE clause

Comment: `Specified cast is not valid.` thats the error I get now.in this line: `st = st + " \n" + dataReader.GetString(counter);`..If u see the code' you probably saw that I'm trying to take values from different columns in datareader.getint32[i] and [i+1]. Is that correct?

Comment: Probably you are trying to read proInfoScienceName (a string) but the counter var you are using is pointing to the second field. Why are using this method to get to your fields content? It's confusing and leads to this kind of errors (for example you don't reset it to zero for the next loop)

Comment: And probably there is another error when you try to read the second reader (you get back only one field, but you ask to GetString(i)). Remember GetString() works on the indexed field of the current record.

Comment: so how can I fix that?and about the dataconnection, I saved the connection.`        private OleDbConnection dataConnection;` so i don't know why to use your method and not mine

Comment: I didn't understand what u tried to do in your edit.and it brings me nothing when I tried it on access software.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10665/discussion-between-noam650-and-steve)